# Android Kotlin set height of FrameLayout programatically not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I am trying like:

```
        fragment_container.layoutParams.height = 100
        fragment_container.requestLayout()
```

or

```
        val params = fragment_container.layoutParams
        params.height = 100
        fragment_container.layoutParams = params
        fragment_container.requestLayout()
```

both does not work, height  of this fragment_container (it is FrameLayout) is still like declared in layout.xml

Here is the layout if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pl.jawegiel.exchangerates.ClickableMotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    motion:layoutDescription="@xml/main_activity_scene">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/exchange_rates"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_header">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_inside_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_title"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/about"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</pl.jawegiel.exchangerates.ClickableMotionLayout>
```

What else do you need to know? What else do you need to know? I suppose I have added everything you need but in case just ask. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After @femi mcpd's corrections it almost work, but there is one more thing left. When I place your code in this method:

```
private fun initToolbarListener() {
    ll_toolbar.addOnLayoutChangeListener { view, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
        llHeaderY =  view.y

        val frameLayout = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.fragment_container)
        frameLayout.layoutParams.height = 400
    }
```

it does not work but I really want to, but if I put this directly in onCreate it works. Why?

Comment: interesting, how do you trigger the change in the ll_toolbar layout?  Can I see your fragment code

Answer (score 0):

Finally all solved. I needed to wrap fragment_contaner with RelativeLayout, and modify this method like this:

```
private fun initToolbarListener() {
    ll_toolbar.addOnLayoutChangeListener { view, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
        llToolbarY = view.y.toInt()

        fragment_container.postDelayed({
            val params = fragment_container.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            params.height = getHeightOfScreenWithoutBars() - llToolbarY - ll_toolbar.height
            fragment_container.layoutParams = params
        }, 100)
    }
}
```

Anyway one more time thank you! Im accepting this question for your commitment :) kind regards